# Solvable model with harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hamiltonian, oscillators, density-operator

I need help with a mathematical physics question.
I have given the following system:

A spin is coupled to a single harmonic oscillator mode with Hamiltonian
$$H=(\epsilon/2) \sigma_{z} + \omega\, a^{\star} a + (\lambda/2) \sigma_{z} \otimes (a^{\star} + a) $$

which acts on the Hilbert space

$$ \mathbb C^{2} \otimes \mathcal H_{\text{osc}} $$
and $a^{\star} a \equiv 1 \otimes a^{\star} a , \sigma_{z}\equiv \sigma_{z} \otimes 1 $.

> **Task**: Calculate explicitly the reduced density spin density matrix
>
> $$\rho(t)= \operatorname{Tr}_{R} (e^{-itH} (\rho(0)\otimes\rho_{R}) e^{itH} ) $$
>
> with the following properties:
>
> $$ \operatorname{Tr}_{R}\rho_{R} e^{(i(a^{\star}+a))}= e^{-1/2 \coth(\beta\omega /2)}$$ and $\rho_{R}=1/Z_{\beta}\times e^{-\beta\omega a^{\star}a}, Z_{\beta}=(1-e^{-\beta\omega})^{-1}$.
>
> Use that $(P_{1}\otimes 1)H=P_{1}\otimes H_{1}$ and $(P_{2}\otimes 1)H=P_{2}\otimes H_{2}$ with
>
> $$H_{1}=(\epsilon/2)  + \omega a^{\star} a + (\lambda/2)  (a^{\star} + a) $$
>
> and
>
> $$H_{2}=-(\epsilon/2)  + \omega a^{\star} a - (\lambda/2)  (a^{\star} + a) $$
>
> and one can use that
>
> $$\rho(t) = \sum _{i,j\in \{1,2\}} P_{i} \rho (0) P_{j} c_{ij}$$
> with $c_{ij}= \operatorname{Tr}_{R}e^{-itH_{i}}\rho_{R}e^{itH_{j}}$.

---

So now when I calculate $c_{ij}$ I get for $i=j$ since $\operatorname{Tr}(A^{-1}BA=\operatorname{Tr}(B))$

$$c_{ii}=\operatorname{Tr}(\rho_{R})=1$$
as $\rho_R$ is a density matrix.

Also if I take $i\neq j$ I can't seem to find an answer. I have so far

$$ c_{21}= \operatorname{Tr}_{R}e^{-itH_{2}}\rho_{R}e^{itH_{1}} = \operatorname{Tr}_{R}e^{itH_{1}}e^{-itH_{2}}\rho_{R}$$

I realize I should be using property 1 here but can't seem how.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You surely mean $\sigma_z\equiv \sigma_z\otimes 1$ in your explication above, right?